# if-else not working in for loop for string in android

Tags: android, loops, if-statement, for-loop, split

I'm trying to make a calculator. but condition where I am assigning value to num2 is not working. unable to figure out what is wrong with the code.

MainActivity.java

```
    package rihan.calc3;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn0, btnadd, btnsub, btnmul, btndiv, btndot, btneq,
        btnclr;
        RelativeLayout rel;
        TextView txt;

        int dot = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
            btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
            btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
            btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
            btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
            btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
            btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
            btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
            btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
            btnsub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsub);
            btnmul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmul);
            btndiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndiv);
            btndot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndot);
            btneq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btneq);
            btnclr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnclr);
            rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
            txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

            btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn9.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn0.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnadd.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnsub.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnmul.setOnClickListener(this);
            btndiv.setOnClickListener(this);
            btndot.setOnClickListener(this);
            btneq.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnclr.setOnClickListener(this);

            btnclr.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn1:
                txt.append("1");
                break;

            case R.id.btn2:
                txt.append("2");
                break;

            case R.id.btn3:
                txt.append("3");
                break;

            case R.id.btn4:
                txt.append("4");
                break;

            case R.id.btn5:
                txt.append("5");
                break;

            case R.id.btn6:
                txt.append("6");
                break;

            case R.id.btn7:
                txt.append("7");
                break;

            case R.id.btn8:
                txt.append("8");
                break;

            case R.id.btn9:
                txt.append("9");
                break;

            case R.id.btn0:
                txt.append("0");
                break;

            case R.id.btnadd:
                txt.append(" + ");
                dot = 0;
                break;

            case R.id.btnsub:
                txt.append(" - ");
                dot = 0;
                break;

            case R.id.btndiv:
                txt.append(" / ");
                dot = 0;
                break;

            case R.id.btnmul:
                txt.append(" x ");
                dot = 0;
                break;

            case R.id.btneq:
                String[] txt_arr = txt.getText().toString().split(" ");
                String symbol = "i";

                boolean symbol_flag = false;
                int array_index = 0;

                float num1 = 0, num2 = 0, result = 0;

                for (array_index = 0; array_index < txt_arr.length - 1; array_index++) {
                    if (txt_arr[array_index].contains("+")) {
                        symbol = txt_arr[array_index];
                        symbol_flag = true;
                    }

                    else {
                        if (symbol_flag == true) {
                            num2 = Float.parseFloat(txt_arr[array_index]);
                            result = num1 + num2;
                            num1 = result;
                        }

                        else {
                            num1 = Float.parseFloat(txt_arr[array_index]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "result : " + result + ". num1 : " + num1 + ". Symbol is : " + symbol + ". Symbol flag is : "
                        + symbol_flag +". num2 : " + num2 + ". length is : " + txt_arr.length,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // array_index=0;
                break;

            case R.id.btnclr:

                break;

            case R.id.btndot:
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

no operation is being performed on num2. IF condition is not getting processed. however its else condition is working fine

```
                    **else {
                        if (symbol_flag == true) {
                            num2 = Float.parseFloat(txt_arr[array_index]);
                            result = num1 + num2;
                            num1 = result;
                        }**

                        else {
                            num1 = Float.parseFloat(txt_arr[array_index]);
                        }
                    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button        
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn2"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnadd"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn3"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn4"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn5"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnsub"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnadd"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn6"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn4"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn7"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn8"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnmul"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnsub"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn9"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="x"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btndot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn7"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="."
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btndot"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnclr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn0"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="C"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btndiv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnmul"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnclr"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="/"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btneq"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btndot"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:text="="
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btneq"
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

txt1 is of no use. please ignore that.

KINDLY TELL ME WHAT IS WRONG WITH THAT IF CONDITION WITHIN DOUBLE ASTERISKS

```
    for (j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
                    if (str[j].equals("+")) {
                        symbol=str[j];
                    }
                    else if (str[j].equals("-")){
                        symbol=str[j];
                    }
                    else if (str[j].equals("x")){
                        symbol=str[j];
                    }
                    else if (str[j].equals("/")){
                        symbol=str[j];
                    }

                    else{
                        if(symbol=="i")
                            num1 = Float.parseFloat(str[j]);
                        else{
                            num2 = Float.parseFloat(str[j]);
                            if (str[j].equals("+")) {
                                result=num1+num2;
                            }
                            else if (str[j].equals("-")){
                                result=num1-num2;
                            }
                            else if (str[j].equals("x")){
                                result=num1*num2;
                            }
                            else if (str[j].equals("/")){
                                result=num1/num2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

still not working. :(

as toast is showing symbol flag value = true then it is surely getting its value.

updated

```
        String[] txt_arr = txt.getText().toString().split(" ");
        String symbol = "i";

        boolean symbol_flag = false;
        int array_index = 0;

        float num1 = 0, num2 = 0, result = 0;

        for (array_index = 0; array_index < txt_arr.length; array_index++) {
            if (txt_arr[array_index].equals("+") || txt_arr[array_index].equals("-")
                    || txt_arr[array_index].equals("x") || txt_arr[array_index].equals("/")) {
                symbol = txt_arr[array_index];
                symbol_flag = true;
            }

            else {
                if (symbol_flag == true) {

                    num2 = Float.parseFloat(txt_arr[array_index]);
                    if (txt_arr[array_index].equals("+")) {
                        result = num1 + num2;
                        num1 = result;
                    }

                    else if (txt_arr[array_index].equals("-")) {
                        result = num1 - num2;
                        num1 = result;
                    }

                    else if (txt_arr[array_index].equals("x")) {
                        result = num1 * num2;
                        num1 = result;
                    }

                    else if (txt_arr[array_index].equals("/")) {
                        result = num1 / num2;
                        num1 = result;
                    }
                }

                else {
                    num1 = Float.parseFloat(txt_arr[array_index]);
                }
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "result : " + result + ". num1 : " + num1 + ". Symbol is : " + symbol + ". Symbol flag is : "
                        + symbol_flag + ". num2 : " + num2 + ". length is : " + txt_arr.length,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: KINDLY DON'T SHOUT!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "if" is not reached, the "symbol" is never set. Are you sure that

```
if (txt_arr[array_index].contains("+"))
```

works as intended? Wouldn't ".equals" be more clear?

[edit]
Also, the test for `symbol_flag == true` is not done in the same iteration in which it is set. There's an "else" between. You should let the loop run one more time, after the symbol flag has been set.

```
for (array_index = 0 ; array_index < txt_arr.length ; array_index++) {
```

Comment: I entered 01 + 2 and the toast it showed was **result:0.0. num1 : 1.0. Symbol flag is : true. num2 : 0.0. length is : 3**

Comment: edited post. tried equals also. used for loop. still the same

Comment: for (array_index = 0; array_index < txt_arr.length ; array_index++) {

Comment: i had used contains() to make sure symbols +,-,/,x are detected even is string contains spaces

Comment: Christine can you please try the original code i posted in your system and find the solution.? and if too long to post here. then can you please mail it to me? I'll be really grateful to you..my email address is rihanaster@gmail.com . I've tried everything you've said. its just not entering inside third nested if condition.

Comment: have you tried the line I posted, with "array_index < txt_arr.length"  (without the -1)?

Comment: its wo9rking now. thanks :) and I'm extremely sorry for troubling

Comment: hehehehe..i really dont know why was it not working before. well probably i must be missing something else of course. pardon me as I'm just a beginner. but still have issue with nested if condition. I'll update in a while.